# Fowler's Patterns: Dealing with table inheritance in a specific way

Tags: java, php, oop, design-patterns, inheritance

These days I'm reading Martin Fowler's Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture, it's really great.

Since I kinda started an OO PHP project (app backend) I want to use Data Mapper for my Domain Model. I read about Table inheritance and I noticed there are 3 types of it.

I don't like Single because I will have more than few types of entries, which will be subclassed from the base class/type. In this case I would have lots of empty space in the db.

I don't see the other two being suitable either.

That is due to my plan of having:

1. Base class (Entry)
2. Subclass (example: StateInstitution extends Entry)
3. Subclass (example: CompanyAffiliate extends Entry)
   ....

The main point here is that I intend to be saving the extra info of the subclasses into a common table tbl_entrymeta - that is, I can have many subclasses that extend from the base Entry class, but not a separate table for each (just one, tbl_entrymeta).

My question is: How to use Data Mapper in this scenario? Is the key in creating inheritance mappers? Or metadata mappers are the key?

Comment: "Domain model" is a term that describes the sum of accumulated knowledge for particular business domain. Said knowledge in code is embodied using [domain pbjects](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DomainObject).

Answer (score -1):

Create a Data Mapper class for the common table (EntryMeta) which represents the object of the relational database table tbl_entrymeta. This object will hold the meta of the subclasses within 3 Fields (columns):

```
1. SubClass
2. FieldName
3. FieldType
```

This way you can easily store the meta of all the sub-classes that inherit the base class and extend it with additional fields of information.

Comment: The point of data mapper patter is to separate the storage details from domain logic.